# jQuery Showing part of the page

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying with jQuery show part of the site, in this example text of menu. I write this code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
 body{ font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; }
 #new-nav{width: auto; height: 200px;}
 </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Menu:</b>
<ol id="new-nav"></ol>

<script>
  $("#new-nav").load("http://site.com/ #hmenus");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

code syntax is correct, but code not work, not showing text.

Comment: You can't load an url external page from your site, is a javascript security rule, maybe you need change your code to some ajax implement. Please read the documentation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: As others have pointed out, this could be a same-origin policy problem; but since you've shown neither the real URL, your own site's URL or stated whether they're on the same domain, we don't know that's the problem. Can you tell us if there are any errors reported in your JavaScript error console?

Comment: David Thomas how to check error in JavaScript error console, I have FireBug it's possible do with this add-on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load content from another domain due to security concerns. 
 See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
You can verify this by looking in your browsers console window.

Also why do you have  #hmenus" at the end of the your URL.

Comment: That would identify the portion of the remote page to load; the `load()` method takes two parameters (both in the same string), first the URL of the page, then the CSS identifier of the part of the page to use/load (if not the whole page). Take a look at the [API for `load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: +1 thanks I've learnt something there :)